# Can I get a reference from a JPA bean to the EntityManager instance that manages it?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

The question basically sums it up.

Play framework has the JPABase class that JPA beans inherit from. This class has a method called em() which returns the bean's entityManager instance. Is there something equivalent to this in plain JPA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, no. And I would find it very questionable. JPA entities are supposed to be POJOs usable outside of the persistence layer, where the JPA classes are not even in the classpath. Exposing the EntityManager in those POJOs seems wrong to me.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I suspected as much. It just seems very restrictive not to be able to access the the EntityManager, so that I can, for example, create a new related object from the bean itself (without having to create an entirely new entityManager).

For example, if I have a "company" object, I want to have a method called "createEmployee()" that would create and persist a related Employee object. Seems like I can't do this from the context of the bean.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Play Framework implements the [Active Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) pattern allowing you to make persistence operations directly in the bean. This is perfectly acceptable and you can implement a similar solution.

However, once you choose this approach, you will not have the benefits of POJOs. For example, this solution may not be the best alternative if your application has n-tier architecture.

Anyway take a look at the source code, it's free!
https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/db/jpa/JPABase.java